# /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control not writable, follow xhci_hcd debug guide

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, root, read-write, debugfs

I want to [follow this tutorial](https://burzalodowa.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-enable-and-tune-dynamic-debugging-for-xhci/). But I can't write to `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`- or `[debugfs]/dynamic_debug/control`-file as suggested by the guide, even tough I am `root`, the special filesystem is mounted `rw` and the `control`-file has `rw`-mode for `root`.

How can I make the `control`-file writable?

I also have another side question. I will ask it, if I may:

All lines in the `control`-file look like this:

```
# filename:lineno [module]function flags format
init/main.c:782 [main]initcall_blacklisted =p "initcall %s blacklisted\012"
```

The guide asks me to add the following line:

```
echo 'module xhci_hcd +p' > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control
```

So is this the way to go? Or is there something *terribly wrong* with writing the above line to the `control`-file, that may break my system or anything?

Answer (score 2):

So this does not solve the problem on how to write to `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`, but solves my problem on how to [follow the tutorial/guide above](https://burzalodowa.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-enable-and-tune-dynamic-debugging-for-xhci/).

In the guide it says you can enable `xhci_hcd`-debugging by adding this line:

```
xhci_hcd.dyndbg=+p
```

as a kernel parameter when booting.

*For doing this only once*, press `e`, when you are in the grub-menu (after starting the computer) : Then you need to find the (correct) line after the keyword `menuentry`, which starts with `linux`. Add the above line behind something like `quiet` or `quiet splash`.

This can also be made permanent in grub(2):

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` with (root) write permission.
2. Add the string above to either `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (the former affects both regular and recovery modes, while the latter affects only regular boots). For example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="xhci_hcd.dyndbg=+p [other stuff]"`.
3. Save the file.
4. Run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Pressing 'e' on the grub console to edit the command directly is a simple way to enable it for a single session.

Comment: @ricab Yeah, I was aware of this, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I don't think editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly is advised. The file to edit is `/etc/default/grub`. An `update-grub` command is required afterwards. That cmd takes configuration input from multiple sources to generate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Grub is updated automatically in some occasions (e.g. when updating the kernel), so manual changes in the boot file would be overwritten.

Comment: I was referring to grub2.

Comment: @ricab sorry, I was wrong: `update-grub` is correct for `grub2` (so is `grub-mkconfig` which is referred to by `update-grub`). You may edit the answer, if you know what configs to change.

Comment: Sure, I just did that (currently awaiting review). Cheers